# A SQL db design (USERS and VIDEOMAKERS)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I've to make a relational database, where there are users and videomakers, every user can request a video to a videomaker and then the videomaker will deliver the video to the user, but I dont know how handle this situation in a db, Should I make one table for the users, one for the videomakers and one connection table that contains the "request" where I put the userId the videomakerId and the text of the request??

Because I have to inform every videoMaker if he have requests from users.

Like this:

[image: Like this:]

is this a good solution?

Thanks, 
Davide

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram looks ok and it's normalized.

For more complex situations, Use a tool to design the Database.  A well-known tool is the [Entity-Relationship Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).   Essentially;  Identify all the entities and then establish the relationships between the entities.

You also need to know about [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Mmmh ok, and when one request is served (the videomaker has delivered the video), should I just change the status of the record, or maybe is better create a table "request served" that contain all request that are served

Comment: Just set the status to request served, or if keeping a history as @Brian suggested insert as row with status request server.  Actually creating a table for just that is not a good idea.

Comment: ok thanks! Should I create a table for the videos or it dosen't have sense?because the videos will be created from the videomaker only when they receive a request. And the user must see the list of all received videos.. @Belayer

Comment: You have to analyse the requirements carefully.  Make a note of all the things that you need to capture such as Date/Time of Request and Date/Time Served,  etc.   From that, you can deduce the entities that you need and the attributes for each entity.   It's difficult to give the actual diagram without the full requirements.  Every bit of information (Attribute) that you need must be noted.

Comment: I would probably change the name table "Request" to something more general such as Service.  In this way, it reflects all pertinent attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good start.  To track status changes, you might want to add a Request Status table:

```
RequestStatus
    RequestStatusID
    RequestID
    Status      --maybe text, maybe a lookup into a Status table
    StatusDate
```

Then you can keep a history of each request.

Comment: mmh sorry I'm a beginner but I dont understand why use this table, is not a good solution to just put an attribut in the request table, and change it when the status changes (for ex. when the video is delivered I'll change the status from 'pending' in "delivered")?

Comment: You can do that if you only ever want the current status.  A RequestStatus table lets you keep a history.  For example: created on the 4th, started production on the 5th, finished on the 8th, delivered on the 10th.

Comment: ah ok, so the RequestID should be part of the primaryKEY with the RequestStatusID right? @Brian

Comment: @Dave, I would just have RequestStatusID as the PKey; in my mind RequestID is only for the foreign key relationship back to the Request table.  I don't think there's one "right" answer to that question, though.

Comment: oh ok right! and in your opinion when the videomaker deliver the video is correct to just update the table request and edit the attribute "video_url" and fill it with the video url? Or I need a table for videos too? @Brian

Comment: @Dave welcome to the wonderful world of database normalization :)  If each request results in a single video, then you could make that an attribute of the Request record.  If not, then you might need a separate table.  I don't know your requirements well enough to say.